# Missing access rights to other partitions

Tags: permissions, ntfs

I have Windows 7 dual booting with Ubuntu 12.04 installed in another partition

How can I edit my documents and copy files or create folders in my other three partitions partitions?

Trying to edit a document I get the error:

> This doc can't be edited, possibly due to missing access rights.  Do you want to edit a copy of the doc?

I used the NTFS configuration tool to mount my drives.

Answer (score 2):

run **sudo nautilus** in terminal

---

input password

---

and your should be able to edit all the files and folders on that partition. You can even give permissions to the current user by right clicking >>**properties>>permissions**

---

Comment: - If you use sudo it is better to use `gksu nautilus`; - Be careful when doing this: some files depend on being set to a specific permission or a user (notably some files in /home/$USER). Do what is necessary and close nautilus ;)

Answer (score 1):

Change the owner and group on the mountpoint.

Example:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1       441G  194G  225G  47% /discworld
```

and

```
discworld@schijfwereld:/$ ls -l /
drwxrwxr-x  11 discworld discworld  4096 Mar 29 22:15 discworld
```

I did this with a

```
sudo chown -R discworld:discworld /discworld
```

and all files belong to my Ubuntu account.

Comment: I got my permissions access to other partitions back with NTF configuration tool.  Open it /advance and I mounted the partitions again

Comment: @carlos I am not into windows tools so good job! ;)